# Calculating pullback of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, dual-spaces, pullback

I'm having some issues understanding the pullback of a linear transformation. Specifically I'm doing some exercises from a differential geometry book of Andrew McInerney.

The question is 
[image]

$G_0$ is the standard inner product and $S$ takes the determinant of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. They ask to calculate $T^*G_0$ and $T^*S$. But since $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, at composing the two functions, $G_0$ would take values from  $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ values from $=\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$, this causes me confusion, because according to the definition $T^*S=S(T)$ and that would be undefined.

Comment: I'm guessing they mean $T^*G(v,w) = G(Tv,Tw)$, and similarly for $S$. Does your book define pullback of bilinear forms so you can confirm?

Comment: Oh! yes, thank you, the pullback of a Bilinear form is defined in another section that wasn't assigned but they define it exactly the way you did. It is really easy now.